# PHP json_encode array to javascript associative array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some columns in mysqli that I'm reading from PHP. It's fetching and echoing perfectly.

```
$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $querystring));
echo json_encode($results);

//$results = {"title":"Sea Shells","location":"./Sea Shells.txt","type":"text"}
```

however, javascript/jquery then reads the echo as a string:

```
var contentarr = [];
(ajax magic here, success: function(results){
    contentarr = results;
});
contentarr[0] = {
contentarr[1] = "
```

how could I directly read an associative array from PHP and map it to an associative array in Javascript? Jquery is the only library I'm using.

Comment: In JavaScript the equivalents to php's `json_[de|en]code()` is JSON.stringify and JSON.parse - https://medium.com/mindorks/json-parse-and-json-stringify-in-javascript-4de609c19d46

Comment: If you're using jQuery's ajax method you should already get a JSON.parsed object as results - _IF_ you set the right content headers (`header('Content-Type: application/json');`) in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`contentarr = results;`
To
`contentarr = JSON.parse(results);`

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

This converts to a javascipt object.

Comment: truly a blessing